# Java OOP class Matrix method equals

Tags: java, oop, matrix, methods, equals

Update:
My program always returns false when I check two matrices for equality. Initialization and copy are working correctly, I can verify through the console that both matrices are the same after being printed. No matter what I do the equals method always returns false!

```
// Class Matrix (Matrix.java)
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Matrix {  
private int size;
private int[][] table = new int[MAX][MAX];


//Default constructor
public Matrix() {
size = 0;
}

//Alternate constructor
public Matrix(int s) {
size = s;
}

//Method to initiate a matrix with random values
  public void init(int low, int up) {
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
      for (int c = 0; c < size; c++)
        table[r][c] = rand.nextInt(up - low + 1) + low;
    }
  }

//Method to copy the matrix
public void copy(Matrix a) {
  for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < size; c++)
      table[r][c] = a.table[r][c];
  }
}

//Method to compare two matrices for equality
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (obj instanceof Matrix) { 
      Matrix otherMatrix = (Matrix) obj;
      for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < size; c++)
          //problem solved!
          //previous:
          //result = (table[r] == otherMatrix.table[r] && table[c] == otherMatrix.table[c]);
          //fixed
          result = (table[r][c] == otherMatrix.table[r][c]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Client for testing:

```
first.init(LOW, UP);
System.out.println("The original matrix is:");
first.print();
System.out.println("The copy of this matrix is: ");
result.copy(first);
result.print();
System.out.println("Testing for equality. Should be equal!!");
if (result.equals(first))
  System.out.println("The matrices are equal!!");
else
  System.out.println("The matrices are NOT equal!!");
```

Comment: What if `size` is zero? Also, I think you might want to re-think the logic in your loop (your inner loop will only run once before returning).

Comment: Your for could run 0 times, and then no return statement

Comment: initialize a boolean with default false, change it if necessary and return it in the end. You're returning a value inside the loop but the loop may never begin.

Comment: try my solution it will work

Comment: Try some debugging or printing of sub-results.
Print out otherMatrix in the Equals method. If that is correct, then inside the for loop the values and why they won't be the same.

Comment: Printed otherMatrix inside the equals method, verifying that otherMatrix was in fact copied correctly and is the same as "first".
Still returning a false... Seems like it is something in the equals method that is not updating result to TRUE.

Comment: Made a small change to the equals method. Program is running correctly now! Thank you so much for your feedback and help

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  boolean match = false;
  if (obj instanceof Matrix) { 
    Matrix otherMatrix = (Matrix) obj;
    for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
      for (int c = 0; c < size; c++)
        match = (table[r] == otherMatrix.table[r] && table[c] == otherMatrix.table[c]);
    }
  }
  return match ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for` cycle could run 0 times, and that would yield to no return statement.
You could update to something like this.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (obj instanceof Matrix) { 
          Matrix otherMatrix = (Matrix) obj;
          // I copied your logic here, are you sure it is correct? -->
          for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
              for (int c = 0; c < size; c++)
                result = table[r] == otherMatrix.table[r] && table[c] == otherMatrix.table[c];
          }
          // <--
    }
    return result;
}

// testing part removed, because lack of context
```

Comment: Will not run zero time because I have input validation before entering this method to make sure the size is greater than 0. I am not sure if my client is to blame now, but I am always getting a false return. See comment above for client

Comment: I understand that, but the compiler probably not. Compilers can't always check context around your code to make sure that it will run. (They are getting better at it though). However by definition `for` cycle can run 0 times. That's what the compiler sees and that's why it throws error.

Comment: Can you post your matrix class to the question?

Comment: So I am no longer getting a compiler error, it accepts the method.

Are you saying that this method might be running zero times, and thus never changing the boolean to true?

Comment: What is the easiest way to attach something that large? I am new to this place, sorry.

Comment: You mean the class is very large? You could add just the relevant parts. The Equals method was a good choice, maybe constructor and an example code part of creating 2 matrix objects and running Equals on them.

Comment: I did not add all methods, but copy and print work as they should. When I run my program I can see both matrices printed and both of them are the same.

Comment: Can you rather edit the question, then others can still come up with ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my program, I want to sincerely thank you for your help :)

My program always returns false when I check two matrices for equality. Initialization and copy are working correctly, I can verify through the console that both matrices are the same after being printed. No matter what I do the equals method always returns false!

```
// Class Matrix (Matrix.java)
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Matrix {  
private int size;
private int[][] table = new int[MAX][MAX];


//Default constructor
public Matrix() {
size = 0;
}

//Alternate constructor
public Matrix(int s) {
size = s;
}

//Method to initiate a matrix with random values
  public void init(int low, int up) {
    Random rand = new Random(); 
    for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
      for (int c = 0; c < size; c++)
        table[r][c] = rand.nextInt(up - low + 1) + low;
    }
  }

//Method to copy the matrix
public void copy(Matrix a) {
  for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < size; c++)
      table[r][c] = a.table[r][c];
  }
}

//Method to compare two matrices for equality
  public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    boolean result = false;
    if (obj instanceof Matrix) { 
      Matrix otherMatrix = (Matrix) obj;
      for (int r = 0; r < size; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < size; c++)
          //problem solved!
          //previous:
          //result = (table[r] == otherMatrix.table[r] && table[c] == otherMatrix.table[c]);
          //fixed
          result = (table[r][c] == otherMatrix.table[r][c]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Client for testing:

```
first.init(LOW, UP);
System.out.println("The original matrix is:");
first.print();
System.out.println("The copy of this matrix is: ");
result.copy(first);
result.print();
System.out.println("Testing for equality. Should be equal!!");
if (result.equals(first))
  System.out.println("The matrices are equal!!");
else
  System.out.println("The matrices are NOT equal!!");
```